# Removing index files from the URL with Nginx

Tags: nginx, seo, location, url-rewriting

At work we are switching from a shared LAMP stack to a VPS running nginx. I'm significantly more comfortable with Apache but learning to use Nginx has been pretty exciting (or as exciting as learning to configure a new webserver can be.

**The current issue is this:** on several domains we need to remove index.php from the URL for canonicalization. This is the last thing that we currently need to take care of for these domains.

I've been researching plenty of different techniques for removing index.php from a URL (most of which are specifically for CI or ExpressionEngine) and I've tried to adapt several of these for personal use but I end up with an infinite loop error which I can only imagine is related to the following:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
}
```

I'm hell-bent on learning how all of this works but right now I need to ask for help figuring this out so that we can move forward and I can figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong.

I would greatly appreciate any responses and will further appreciate anyone who is willing to go a little in-depth on the subject to help someone new like myself and anyone else who might be in a similar situation that reads this.

**Thank you!**

**UPDATE**
To make things easier I'm just going to put my nginx config up here for this vhost.

```
server  {
    listen          80;
    server_name     examplesite.com;
    # redirect non-www to www. for canonical urls
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.examplesite.com/$1 permanent; 
}

server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     www.examplesite.com;

    error_log   /srv/http/nginx/examplesite.com/log/nginx-error.log;
    access_log  /srv/http/nginx/examplesite.com/log/nginx-access.log;

    root  /srv/http/nginx/examplesite.com/root;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include        fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param  PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "error_log=/srv/http/nginx/examplesite.com/log/php-error.log";
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    }
```

}

Comment: If you need to pass the args use something like `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/$uri&$args;` What the `$args =404`?

Comment: And use the `last` parameter (aka `[L]` in apache). For the CI it will be something like `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?/$uri last;`

Comment: The site in question is a simple static site. Nothing gets passed through index.php like CI does. I simply need to remove index.php from the URL for canonicalization.

Comment: It uses `.php` so not so static. I think that index.php uses some GET parameter to handle urls (e.g. `index.php?q=somepage`) so in this case you can `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args last;`. But in any case please provide more information about your schema or just read more about [nginx configuration](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration)

Comment: index.php is nearly entirely static. This site isn't running off of a framework or anything. It is literally one page + a separate file to handle the form action.  My question is about forcing www.example.com/index.php to rewrite to www.example.com for canonical reasons. This won't break anything going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
server  {
    listen          80;
    server_name     examplesite.com;
    # redirect non-www to www. for canonical urls
    # proper way to do this
    rewrite ^ http://www.examplesite.com$request_uri? permanent; 
}

server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     www.examplesite.com;

    error_log   /srv/http/nginx/examplesite.com/log/nginx-error.log;
    access_log  /srv/http/nginx/examplesite.com/log/nginx-access.log;

    root  /srv/http/nginx/examplesite.com/root;

    # add index under server as you have done for root
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        # drop the "=404". Nginx will return 404 by itself if not found.
        # note the "last" should not be added to "try_files"
        # whether you need something after "$uri/" depends on your setup.
        # this should do for most unless running WP etc
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # Return '400 Bad Request' for malformed URLs
        # See: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Pass_Non-PHP_Requests_to_PHP.
        location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
            return 400;
        }

        # Rewrite "index.php" requests
        rewrite ^(.*)index.php(.*)$ $1$2    permanent;

        # continue for other php and rewritten "index.php" requests 
        include        fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param  PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "error_log=/srv/http/nginx/examplesite.com/log/php-error.log";
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    }

    ...


}
```

Not 100% about the index.php rewrite line as there is a chance it might put you in a redirect loop.  If that is the case, then the answer is to just serve the index.php requests but change all links in the application to remove them so that they disappear over time.

Answer (score 0):

At first, Check your index directive

```
server {
  index index.php index.html;
  ...
```

Then be sure that php is properly handling by your configured backend

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass    backend;
}
```

Where backend is the configured earlier upstream, for ex:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Look at the [VirtualHost example](http://wiki.nginx.org/VirtualHostExample)

Comment: I've added my original vhost config file for reference. This answer doesn't contain anything relative to the rewrite.

Comment: This answer contain the `index`. You wrote _My question is about forcing www.example.com/index.php to rewrite to www.example.com_ Not the redirect from `/index.php` to `/`. So no rewrite rules required, read more about [HttpIndexModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpIndexModule)

Comment: Bear in mind that using "location ~ \.php$ {" is usually insecure. See: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Pass_Non-PHP_Requests_to_PHP

Comment: From your link: *The proper solution is to set cgi.fix_pathinfo=0 in php.ini*. But your question is not about security, right? So `index` directive is helped you?

Comment: I didn't ask the question and have no comment on that. I just wanted to point out to both of you that the shown configuration is usually insecure.